# check the segue used to open viewController in the viewController itself

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

Having this methods:

```
//Metodo che verifica se proveniamo dal Profile controller o da un altro controller
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "accountSegue" {
        self.DisattivaTutorialBtn.isHidden=true
         IndietroBtn.isHidden=false
    }else{
        self.IndietroBtn.isHidden=true
        self.DisattivaTutorialBtn.isHidden=false
    }


}
```

I perform different actions basing on the segue's identifier.
Of course, this method isn't called anywhere (I understood that it is): how can I call it? It seems stupid but calling it as "self" method in "viewDidLoad" doesn't work.

Comment: To do that instead of performing your Segue on a button click in storyboard, create a segue from your viewcontroller to your other view controller. the when you want o go to the next view controller call self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "accountSegue", sender: self)

Comment: You need to call performseguewithidentifier

Comment: call performSegueWithIdentifier method

Comment: How are you *creating* your segue? Do you have, for example, a button, and you ctrl-drag from the button to a different View Controller, select "Show" and then you give that new Segue an identifier of "accountSegue"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that instead of performing your Segue on a button click in storyboard, create a segue from your viewcontroller to your other view controller. then when you want to go to the next view controller call below from your button click or any other action event.

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "accountSegue", sender: self)
```

This will automatically call your prepareForSegue method and your if statement will execute.

Comment: The problem is that i want to perform it by code instead of using UI elements. How can I perform segue in this way?

Comment: How are you creating a segue? In order to create a Segue, you need to use Storyboards. If you are not using storyboards and want to do everything programatically then you cannot do it this way. Then you have to manage your controllers in a stack using push and pop methods.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using manual segues in your Storyboard, you can perform the segue by calling `self.performSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`. See [performSegue documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621413-performsegue).
If you are using segues whose type is not set to manual, when you click on the UI element to which the segue is linked in your Storyboard, `prepare(for segue)` will be called automatically by the system.

Comment: I mustn't use UI elements to perform the segue: I want perform it through code. How can I?

Comment: Segues are designed to work only with Storyboard, hence the name `UIStoryboardSegue`. If you are not using a `Storyboard`, you need to manually present your view controllers, using `yourViewController.present(_:animated:completion:)` or `yourViewController.show(_:sender:)`. In this case, you cannot use `prepare(for segue)` either to send data between the view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

To perform Segue manually you need to attach the action
Following will help you go get the required thing done

```
performSegue(withIdentifier: "accountSegue", sender: nil)
```